# How to make a NuGet package for this PCL library

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, nuget

I'm trying to create a nuget package for a PCL library I've made.

[image]

This nuget package is intended to be used in a **Xamarin Forms** application though. So I'm not even sure if the things I've ticked are correct.

I *really* only care about .NET Framework 4. That is **my** bare minimum framework. For the rest, I don't care at all and have no idea what I should be targetting.

For what it's worth, I'm using [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/) to create my NuGet `nupkg` files to *manually* test them before I publish them to NuGet.

Here's a screenshot of what I was trying, but Xamarin Studio failed to add the nuget package (saying it wasn't the right something-or-rather).

[image]

and the error message from Xam Studio:

```
Adding Foo...
Adding 'Foo 1.3.0' to Core.
Could not install package 'Foo 1.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+wp80+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarinios10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Xamarin.Forms the two profiles that are good ones for your Portable Class Library (PCL) project to use are Profile 78 or Profile 259. Xamarin.Forms can be used in other profiles but if your PCL project targets one of these you should be OK. Your project looks to be targeting Profile 78.

Here are the Xamarin.Forms PCL profiles for reference.

Xamarin.Forms 1.3:

```
portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10
```

Xamarin.Forms 1.4:

```
portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10
```

The problem with your NuGet package that it does not indicate that it supports Windows 8 in the PCL. NuGet will look at all the individual frameworks that make up the project's PCL profile (ignoring the Xamarin and Mono ones since they are optional if you do not have them in your NuGet package's PCL profile) and ensure that the NuGet package's PCL profile has a framework which is compatible. If the NuGet PCL does not have a matching framework then NuGet considers it incompatible.

So your NuGet package's portable library folder would need to include win

```
portable-net4+sl5+wp8+win
```

Then you can install your NuGet package into your Profile 78 PCL project.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the detailed reply, _really_ appreciated it! I do have a question: What does `+win` mean? Also, what's the diff between the last folder and the Xam Forms 1.4 folder, above?

Comment: The '+' is just a separator. win is the short name for the Windows 8 framework. The 8 is implied based on NuGet's rules.

Comment: The difference between your NuGet PCL folder and Xamarin.Forms - Xamarin.Forms supports Net 4.5 but not Net 4.0, and it does not target Silverlight (sl). Xamarin.Forms 1.4 also only supports Windows 8.1 and above but also supports the new Windows Phone 8 projects (wpa). wp = Windows Phone Silverlight.