# How do I create a Nuget for my Xamarin Forms Project?

Tags: nuget, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I have written a package for Xamarin Forms Portable + Android + iOS.  MOST of the code is in the portable class.  One renderer (for an "HtmlLabel") requires platform specific code in Android and iOS. The package requires a somewhat long list of Nugets as dependencies. Some of these Nugets require minimal platform specific code to, for example, initialize.

I have been searching everywhere for a straightforward tutorial on how to turn my code into a Nuget.  I'd like to be able to do this for my own projects as well as to share it with the universe.

Resources:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953323/not-sure-how-to-make-a-nuget-package-for-this-pcl-library), [this](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/), [this](http://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#From_a_convention_based_working_directory), [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-reusable-plugins-for-xamarin-forms/), [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/afead421-3fbf-489a-a4e8-4a244ecdbb1e).

The James Montemagno stuff is nice, but isn't exactly what I need because it seems to skip steps.

Any help?

Comment: Bumpety bump bump bump.

Comment: I'm looking for a fist bump.